# node.js variable scopes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I havethe following exported object:

```
module.exports = {
    value: 0,

    startTimer: function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            value++;
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

How can I access `value` from that setInterval function?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either specify the full path to the value:

```
module.exports = {
    value: 0,

    startTimer: function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            module.exports.value++;
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Or, if you bind the function called by `setTimeout` to `this`, you can use `this`:

```
module.exports = {
    value: 0,

    startTimer: function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            this.value++;
        }.bind(this), 1000);
    }
}
```

This is similar to code like this, which you will see from time to time:

```
module.exports = {
    value: 0,

    startTimer: function() {
        var self = this;
        setInterval(function() {
            self.value++;
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```